# An identity of generating functions

Tags: probability-theory

Let $N$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb N_0$ and $X_1, X_2, ...$ i.i.d with values in $\mathbb N_0$ and independent of $N$. For $n \in \mathbb N$ let $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} X_k$. Define $S_N: S_N(\omega):= S_{N(\omega)}(\omega)$. Let $g$ and $f$ be the generating functions of $N$ and $X_1$ respectively.

> Show that the generating function of $S_N$ is $\varphi = g \circ f.$

**My idea:**

We know
$$ \varphi (z) = \sum_n \mathbb P(S_N = n) z^n$$ 
and 
$$ g \circ f (z) = \sum_n \mathbb P(N=n) \left( \sum_k \mathbb P(X_1=n) z^k  \right)^n .$$

I can't really find a way to relate these two.

Comment: Strange definition of $S_N$. Don't you mean $S_N:=X_1+\cdots+X_N$?

Comment: Once you've fixed that problem, use the "law of total expectation" by conditioning on $N$.

Comment: @drhab No I mean it as stated

Comment: It is simply not possible to define $S_N$ by a reference to $S_N$ itself. If $S_N$ must be defined - where it is clear what $N$ is - then it must be made clear what $S_n$ is. Is my interpretation wrong? That would be strange because according to my interpretation the generating function is indeed $g\circ f$ as is to be shown.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Forgot to define $S_n$. @drhab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h_X$ denotes the generating function of a random variable $X$ that takes values in $\mathbb N_0$ then:
 $$h_X(z)=\mathsf Ez^{X}$$

Further:$$\mathsf Ez^{S_N}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathsf{E}(z^{S_N}\mid N=n)P(N=n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathsf Ez^{S_n}P(N=n)\tag1$$

Here $$\mathsf Ez^{S_n}=\mathsf{E}z^{X_1+\cdots X_n}=\mathsf E(z^{X_1}\cdots z^{X_n})=\mathsf{E}z^{X_1}\cdots\mathsf Ez^{X_n}=f(z)^n$$

Now substitute in $(1)$ and draw conclusions.